# Sonarlint NullPointException when using IBM JDK 8

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarlint

I'm using IBM JDK 8 for Eclipse Mars (required to connect to WebSphere, Oracle JDK doesn't work). In the eclipse.ini, I added the following:

-vm
C:\IBM\eclipseDevelopmentPackage\ibm_sdk80\jre\bin\javaw.exe

When I run latest version sonarlint 1.2 (installed from eclipse marketplace), I got the following exception. Switch back to Oracle JDK 8, no issue. Any idea?

Also, is it possible to install sonarlint in RAD 8.5.5.1(Eclipse 3.6 based) ?

```
Sensor JavaSquidSensor
Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 6
JavaClasspath initialization...
JavaClasspath initialization done: 213 ms
JavaTestClasspath initialization...
JavaTestClasspath initialization done: 214 ms
Java Main Files AST scan...
1 source files to be analyzed
Error during analysis
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'C:\workspace\........\Service.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:126)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:80)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:135)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:128)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:90)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:185)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:249)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:244)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:133)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:273)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:166)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SonarRunnerFacade.startAnalysis(SonarRunnerFacade.java:55)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeProjectJob$1.run(AnalyzeProjectJob.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:187)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ProgramState.decreaseReference(ProgramState.java:200)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ProgramState.cleanupDeadSymbols(ProgramState.java:244)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.cleanUpProgramState(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:224)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.handleBlockExit(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:232)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.execute(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:175)
    at org.sonar.java.se.ExplodedGraphWalker.visitMethod(ExplodedGraphWalker.java:130)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl.accept(MethodTreeImpl.java:215)
    at org.sonar.java.se.SymbolicExecutionVisitor.visitNode(SymbolicExecutionVisitor.java:41)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:89)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:72)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:65)
    at org.sonar.java.model.InternalVisitorsBridge.visitFile(InternalVisitorsBridge.java:125)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:117)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Same issue exists in Sonar plugin for Eclipse running under IBM JDK7.

Comment: SonarLint 1.2 is pretty old now. We have the feeling the issue was solved by https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1797 so please test with a recent version.